# Oracle How to use distinct on one column

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having this query (Oracle 11g):

```
SELECT 
  distinct to_number(val.number_value), val.variant_number
from
  val
left join
  mad on mad.id = val.madid
where 
  val.id = 227753377 and mad.fk_parent =18468
  and (val.language_id = 6003 or val.language_id is null)
  and mad.identifier = 'IDENTIFIER2'
order by val.variant_number
```

Which returns me:

```
0 | 1
0 | 2
0 | 3 
0 | 4 
0 | 5
```

In this case Oracle dont know what to do, cause it referes to all selected columns, i guess.

What I need in this case above is this result:

```
 0 | 1
```

But in this other example it should give me:

```
0 | 1
1 | 2
2 | 3
```

If val.number_value is a duplicate, then it should be ignored and return me only 1 row for this.
How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If for each `number_value` you want only one `variant_number`, you can use `group by` and some aggregate function (e.g. min/max) :

```
SELECT 
  to_number(val.number_value), min(val.variant_number)
from
  val
left join
  mad on mad.id = val.madid
where 
  val.id = 227753377 and mad.fk_parent =18468
  and (val.language_id = 6003 or val.language_id is null)
  and mad.identifier = 'IDENTIFIER2'
group by to_number(val.number_value)
```

Comment: Thank you. For me this is the easiest way.

Answer (score 2):

```
with numbers as (
  SELECT to_number(val.number_value) as number_value, 
         val.variant_number,
         row_number() over (partition by val.number_value order by val.variant_number) as rn
  from val
    left join mad on mad.id = val.madid
  where val.id = 227753377 and mad.fk_parent =18468
    and (val.language_id = 6003 or val.language_id is null)
    and mad.identifier = 'IDENTIFIER2'
  order by val.variant_number
) 
select number_value, 
       variant_Number
from numbers
where rn = 1;
```

By changing the `order by` in the window function, you can "configure" which row to take from the duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but got an error in "order by" :missing ORDER BY expression in the window specification

Comment: @frgtv10 - there were too many parentheses in the analytic clause; do you want to try that again? (Although using the aggregate `min()` would have the same effect here; this gives you more flexibility if your requirement of which of the duplicate rows to pick is more complicated, e.g. using a date field that isn't included in the `select`).

Comment: @AlexPoole: thanks for fixing my typos. I initially forgot the order by, but when adding it I messed up the code ;)